# Formatting nested lists/tuples

Tags: python, formatting

I have an output (a long one!) from some function, which looks in this way:

```
[[(0.0, 1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 2.0, 0.0), (2.0, 1.0, 0.0)], [(1.6324986294474886e-06, 1.000000272083105, 1.9999992744450537), (1.0, 1.9999985559929883, 9.626713411705526e-07), (1.9999957124111243, 1.000000714598146, 9.527975279416402e-07)], ......................, [(0.00016488526381860965, 1.0000274825531668, 1.9999267116402146), (0.9999999810184469, 1.9998541492231847, 9.723903843230245e-05), (1.9995669148822666, 1.000072183688789, 9.62532545797885e-05)]]
```

I don't like the structure of the output, but it is very convenient to use it in the function, which returns it.

But i need to format the output to look this way:

```
0.0 1.0 2.0 A
1.0 2.0 0.0 B
2.0 1.0 0.0 C
1.6324986294474886e-06 1.000000272083105 1.9999992744450537 A
1.0 1.9999985559929883 9.626713411705526e-07    B
1.9999957124111243 1.000000714598146 9.527975279416402e-07  C
```

I have this code:

```
obj = 'A', 'B', 'C'
for n in results():    
    for z in range(len(results()[0])):
        k = n[z], obj[z]
        print '\t'.join(map(str, k))
```

('results' is the name of the function, which returns the big list)

It gives me this:

```
(0.0, 1.0, 2.0) A
(1.0, 2.0, 0.0) B
(2.0, 1.0, 0.0) C
(1.6324986294474886e-06, 1.000000272083105, 1.9999992744450537) A
(1.0, 1.9999985559929883, 9.626713411705526e-07)    B
(1.9999957124111243, 1.000000714598146, 9.527975279416402e-07)  C
```

I can get this, if I don't add the letter (A, B or C) in the end of the line with this code, so, I thought, maybe to add it somehow differently?

Anyway, hoping for your help!
Thanks in advance!

An unexpected problem... I really want to write the output into a .csv file, so instead of print I use (for now I've chosen the option of using list and appending the letter, as it is more clear to me)

```
with open('table.csv', 'wb') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
    for n in results():    
        for z in range(len(res[0])):
            k = list(n[z])
            k.append(obj[z])
            writer.writerows ('\t'.join(map(str, k)))
```

And it doesn't actually work properly, I only get this:

```
0 
. 
0 
1 
. 
0 
2 
. 
0 
A
.
.
.
```

Why do I get so strange formatting, but not what I get with print? It is quite shocking to me...

Answer (score 5):

If its always going to be of length 3, you should look into the `itertools` module. Something like:

```
import itertools
for num, letter in itertools.izip(itertools.chain.from_iterable(bigList), itertools.cycle('ABC')):
    print '%f\t%s' % (num, letter)
```

Also, I hope youre not actually using `for z in range(len(results()[0])):`, as that will rerun the results function, recalculating the entire list. Just FYI.

Comment: Wow, this idea is new to me, thanks! It is going to be of length 3, but I'd like to leave an opportunity to easily change the length to something different.
Thanks for that tip, BTY, I didn't think about it! Before, it ran for over 3 sec, now - less, than one! I'm just starting programming...

Comment: Oh, and the nice thing about the itertools functions, is that you can use them easily with generator functions or objects. If your bigList really is giant, you may want to look into them.

Comment: Yeah, the itertools stuff is good if youre looking for speed. If you wanted to allow for different lengths, you could just wrap that in a function and use the labels as an argument:

    def f(bigList, labels):

And then just use the labels object instead of 'ABC' in what I had above. The length of the labels object you pass would control the length of the cycle, as well as the characters. so f(bigList, 'ABC') for how you had it before, or f(bigList, 'wxyz') for sublist of 4 with different characters. Hope it helps.

Comment: The length (number of nested lists in the big one) should actually be ~1000 or more, I think. I'll look into it, THX!

Answer (score 1):

The complete program:

```
def results():
    return [[(0.0, 1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 2.0, 0.0), (2.0, 1.0, 0.0)], 
            [(1.6324986294474886e-06, 1.000000272083105, 1.9999992744450537),
             (1.0, 1.9999985559929883, 9.626713411705526e-07), 
             (1.9999957124111243, 1.000000714598146, 9.527975279416402e-07)], 
            [(0.00016488526381860965, 1.0000274825531668, 1.9999267116402146),
             (0.9999999810184469, 1.9998541492231847, 9.723903843230245e-05),
             (1.9995669148822666, 1.000072183688789, 9.62532545797885e-05)]]

obj = 'A', 'B', 'C'
for n in results():    
    for z in range(len(results()[0])):
        k = list(n[z])
        k.append(obj[z])
        print(','.join(map(str, k)))
```

The output:

```
0.0,1.0,2.0,A
1.0,2.0,0.0,B
2.0,1.0,0.0,C
1.63249862945e-06,1.00000027208,1.99999927445,A
1.0,1.99999855599,9.62671341171e-07,B
1.99999571241,1.0000007146,9.52797527942e-07,C
0.000164885263819,1.00002748255,1.99992671164,A
0.999999981018,1.99985414922,9.72390384323e-05,B
1.99956691488,1.00007218369,9.62532545798e-05,C
```

This was checked with python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2.

The implementation adds the letter to the list.  (The list constructor is needed, because a tuple is constant and cannot be changed.)

Comment: An unexpected problem... I really want to write the output into a .csv file, so instead of print I use 
writer.writerows(...).
And i doesn't actually work properly, I only get this:
0
.
0
 
1
.
0
 
2
.
0
 
A

Why do I get so strange formatting, but not what I get with print? It is quite shocking to me...

Comment: You have just to replace the '\t' with a ','.

Comment: This doesn't work... I get this:
0
.
0
","
1
.
0
","
2
.
0
","
A
(in one column)

Comment: I already updated the source: please re-check; it should work.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that You just changed '\t' to ','? If so, it doesn't work...

Comment: I know that, I tried changing it, it doesn't help, just the output is as I've shown previously.

Comment: @Ilya: I added the complete program (including my test result function) and the output.  Can you please re-verify?

Comment: Ah, I get that. The question I asked was about writing that output into a file, that's with what I have a problem. When I print that to stdout evetything is fine, just as you have shown.

Comment: @Ilya: Can you **please** add **all** of your requirements to the question.  This is the second time you redefine your requirements.

Comment: No, it is not, it was only once, and I've already added them rather long time ago - look at the and of the question, it's been there all day (for 22 hours to be exact).

Answer (score 1):

Replace your call to str in the map call to calling a wee function:

```
def foo(lst):
    return ' '.join(map(str,lst))

obj = 'A', 'B', 'C'
for n in results():    
    for z in range(len(results()[0])):
        k = n[z], obj[z]
        print '\t'.join(map(foo, k))
```

Comment: Works as well! Just changed it to 
def foo(lst):   
    return '\t'.join(map(str.lst))

Comment: Isn't the better option to just do ``k = *n[z], obj[z]`` to unpack the tuple so you don't need to do nested joins?

Comment: How to unpack the tuple this way?

Comment: I think unpacking is only valid within the context of a function call.