# Format nested list python

Tags: python

```
list=[['name1', 'maths,english'], ['name2', 'maths,science']]
```

I have a nested list that likes something like this, I am trying to work out how to format it so that the out put would be something like the following:

```
name1, maths,english
name2, maths,science
```

I have tried using regex to no avail. How would I go about formatting or manipulating the list output to get something like the above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting nested lists/tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356424/formatting-nested-lists-tuples)

Comment: Why would regex work? It's for parsing strings, not creating them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was treating the list as a string, I see now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over your groups and join the items from each group using a comma.

```
groups = [['name1', 'maths,english'], ['name2', 'maths,science']]

for group in groups:
    print ', '.join(group)
```

Comment: Note: unlike the original post, Soviut uses `groups` as the name for the variable, since `list` is a standard global function in python. It's usually a good idea to avoid clashes with global names

Comment: The output I'm getting from this is is character on a single line

Comment: I apologise, I fixed my issue above by removing the str() function when getting my output for the list, thanks for the solution greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 you could use [format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) as described in [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)

```py
fmt_groups = "\n".join(["{},{}".format(*group) for group in groups])
print(fmt_groups)
```